# replacing \\ by blank line

Tags: line-breaking

I have a LaTeX document in which paragraphs are separated by double backslashes (`\\`).
However, I would like to separate them by blank lines instead.
I have more than 350 instances of `\\`.

Is there a way to replace them all at once?

I am using Texstudio.

Comment: Welcome. I'm afraid no, if you have some good uses of ``\\`` like in `tabular` or `align` and so on.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to replace things only when they are outside of an align environment?

Comment: You could try to write a regular expression to see if you are in a tabular/align or not, for example replace all instances of a line that does not contain `&`. Or replace all instances and manually put back the ones inside a tabular or align.

Comment: How do I automatically insert a blank line?

Comment: Also 350 seems more feasible than 8000, if you do 6 per minute than you only need one hour to replace them manually.

Comment: Replace by `\n\n`, so two newlines. TexStudio will convert those to actual line endings/empty lines.

Comment: Thank you, Marijn!

Comment: Why are you using  \\ to separate paragraphs? In the LaTeX source a single blankline can separate paragraphs and the length `\parskip` can be used to specify the vertical space between paragraphs.

Comment: I guess someone told me to do it when I learned LaTeX. But now I will not do it again

Comment: I will search every `\begin{tabular}` and replace all \\ inside the environment by `\tabularnewline`  and then the remaining \\ by `\par` instead of blank lines. So, if you have changed something wrongly, the errors are more traceable and without split the source. Once you check that it  can be compiled without problems, feel free to change the `\par` by blank lines and `\tabularnewline`  by \\ if that commands disturb you.

Comment: @Fran the problem then becomes how to determine automatically if you are inside a tabular or not, in order to do the correct replacements.

Comment: @Marjin Is only a problem if you want/need to do automatically. Fix a few (?) tables manually it could be a matter of minutes, whereas find the ideal automatism could be a matter of hours and  end in fiasco for most people not expert in regular expression. I wouldn't mess with that hairy beast unless to be sure of a clear benefit in time.

Comment: @Fran I agree that usually it is not worth it. But if you have a large document with dozens of tables it quickly becomes tedious to fix everything by hand, and an automatic solution may save you some time. Also the question here asked for an automatic solution (even though a non-automatic solution may be better).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. In the end I just replaced every \\ by \n\n manually. It only took 20 minutes